# Javascript Generators with mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, async-await, generator

I am trying to iterate through an array of data and check if it's already in a mongodb collection then append an extra field called duplicate to the data. I was trying to use generators to do this with the [co](https://github.com/tj/co) module. Here is the code that I have. It's working but I don't think it's optimized properly because it's taking forever to loop through 10 records. is there a better way to do this? maybe using even es2017 async/await

```js
co(function *(){
  const data = [....]
  const db = yield MongoClient.connect(url);
  const d = yield data.map(function* (val) {
    let DUP;
    const user = yield db.collection('users').find({phone: val.phone}).toArray();
    if(user.length > 0) {
      DUP = 'YES'
    } else {
      console.log('')
      DUP = 'NO'
    }
    return Object.assign({}, val, {DUPLICATE: DUP})
  })
  console.log(d)
  yield db.close()
});
```